# What does dplyr's arrange() function do if no column argument is specified?

Tags: r, dplyr

I recently came across source code, that applied dplyr's arrange() function without column arguments to a data frame or tibble, e.g. something like this:

```
df %>% arrange()
```

where df is your data frame or tibble.

(1) I was wondering, whether this code (specifically `arrange()`) did anything? Does arrange() change anything in the input, if it is given just the input but no further arguments? Just applying arrange() to the data provided with the source or to `mtcars` did not seem to have an effect, but I was wondering whether there was an edge case, where `arrange()` would actually change something? Or is this some redundant piece of code that I found?

(2) The code I came across is at max. from 2020: If `arrange()` does nothing to the input data nowadays, was there a time where it would modify the input data despite no column argument being provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  A = letters,
  B = rev(LETTERS),
  C = 1:26,
  D = rev(1:26)
)
df %>% 
  head() %>% 
  arrange()
#>   A B C  D
#> 1 a Z 1 26
#> 2 b Y 2 25
#> 3 c X 3 24
#> 4 d W 4 23
#> 5 e V 5 22
#> 6 f U 6 21
```

Let's try the reversed order:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  B = rev(LETTERS),
  A = letters,
  D = rev(1:26),
  C = 1:26
)
df2 %>% 
  head() %>% 
  arrange()
#>   B A  D C
#> 1 Z a 26 1
#> 2 Y b 25 2
#> 3 X c 24 3
#> 4 W d 23 4
#> 5 V e 22 5
#> 6 U f 21 6
```

If you look at the source code you can also see why:

```
#' @rdname arrange
#' @export
arrange.data.frame <- function(.data,
                               ...,
                               .by_group = FALSE,
                               .locale = NULL) {
  dots <- enquos(...)
  
  if (.by_group) {
    dots <- c(quos(!!!groups(.data)), dots)
  }
  
  loc <- arrange_rows(.data, dots = dots, locale = .locale)
  dplyr_row_slice(.data, loc)
}
```

`enquos(...)` evaluates to an empty list if you don't supply anything. And if you run `arrange_rows` with `dots = list()`, it returns the same order as before.

```
dplyr:::arrange_rows(df, dots = list(), locale = NULL)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26
```

In a [version from early 2020](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/4cc84d4797f09b03fd94f81088b8d1a655d68e90/R/arrange.R), it seems even more clear:

```
#' @param .by_group If `TRUE`, will sort first by grouping variable. Applies to
#'   grouped data frames only.
#' @rdname arrange
#' @export
arrange.data.frame <- function(.data, ..., .by_group = FALSE) {
  if (missing(...)) {
    return(.data)
  }

  loc <- arrange_rows(.data, ..., .by_group = .by_group)
  dplyr_row_slice(.data, loc)
}
```

Here the same order is explicitly returned when there are no columns supplied to the dots.

I assume that whoever wrote that code forgot to remove the `arrange()` command after working on the code interactively. Since it has no effect, that can happen easily.

Comment: Cheers! The source code of arrange() also provides a legacy option:

`dplyr_order_legacy <- function(data, direction = "asc") {
  if (ncol(data) == 0L) {
    # Work around `order(!!!list())` returning `NULL`
    return(seq_len(nrow(data)))
  }`

But I reckon, that will also not change much (?).
So maybe the arrange() command was forgotten in the code I saw - it was just weird, since it featured in two prominent positions, and since I am more familiar with base R than with the whole tidyverse stack, I wondered whether I had missed something.